# Finding The Coefficients of the digital filter?

Tags: filter-design

I want to design a digital filter for pulse shaping. Pulses are of 100us Fall time. and the sampling rate is 100MegaSamples/sec. and the Shaping time is 5us. What should my coefficients be??? And how to obtain them using matlab or any other related software.

Comment: I don't understand your requirements. What does the signal look like before it's shaped and how do you want it to look like after the shaping?